# Using jquery in ember app

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js

I'm building an app with ember js and I'm not sure how to use jQuery with ember. An example of what I'm trying to achieve is a page that gets sale data from my api.

in my app.js I've got

```
App.TransactionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Transaction.find();
    }
});
```

If I pass in a start date and an end date to the App.Transaction.find() method my api will restrict the data it sends back to within those dates.

I have a form on the page with an input for the start and end dates and I want to hook this up to jQuery UI's datepicker.

This is where I'm stuck I put this at the end of my ember app code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#transactionsStartDate").datepicker();      
    jQuery("#transactionsEndDate").datepicker();
});
```

but it doesn't do anything and no errors are thrown.

How can I get the jquery to run? also how do I hook up the inputted date variables to the call to `App.Transaction.find({startDate: startDateVariable, endDate: endDateVariable})`

thanks for your help!

**EDIT**
Correction the jQuery is running but it's running before the view is rendered. Does ember have a hook or something that I can call when my view is rendered?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of putting the datepicker initialization in jQuery(document).ready() hook into the didInsertElement method of the view

```
App.TransactionsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'transactions',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        jQuery("#transactionsStartDate, #transactionsEndDate").datepicker();    
    }
});
```

use Ember's built in TextField view

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="transactions">
<form>
    <label for="transactionsStartDate">Start Date</label>
    {{view Ember.TextField id="transactionsStartDate" valueBinding="startDate"}}
    <label for="transactionsEndDate">End Date</label>
    {{view Ember.TextField id="transactionsEndDate" valueBinding="endDate"}}
    <button {{action fetchTransactions}}>Fetch Data</button>
</form>
</script>
```

and define the action fetchTransactions on the controller

```
App.TransactionsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    fetchTransactions:function() {
        this.set('model', App.Transaction.find({startDate:this.get('startDate'), endDate:this.get('endDate')}));    
    }
});
```

Comment: What about with the Ember 2.0 version? Views are deprecated in it.

Comment: @MaksimLuzik it's still didInsertElement on the 2.0 components. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_integrating-with-third-party-libraries-with-code-didinsertelement-code