# Losing 'this' reference when going to a route

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have an irritating problem with ember.js. So I have a {{#link-to}} to some of the routes defined in App.js:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#link-to 'signup' class='signup-window'}} SIGN UP {{/link-to}}
    {{#link-to 'login' class='signup-window'}} LOGIN {{/link-to}}
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

So this is my root template. When I click on the signup link, I want to render the signup template. And actually it does so. The problem comes with the script I have for that links:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.signup-window').click(function() {
        var signupBox = $(this).attr('href').replace("/", "");
        /*Here is the rest of the script where I manipulate the template.*/
        });
    });
</script>
```

So I want to get the value of the 'href' attribute of the clicked link. But in the way I do it the actual flow is the following: I click the link, the script is performed but ember hasn't rendered the template yet and the part where I manipulate that template in the script is not working, because practically there is no template to manipulate. So I decided to do a work around(which is not a good practice, but I do it only to test if it will work) and I set timeout when I click on the link in order to have a rendered template by ember. But when I did so I understand that actually I lose 'this' reference(the  tag). So what is supposed to do in that situation?

Comment: Can you put this into a JSBin? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery in EmberJS can be accessed via:

```
elememt = this.$();
```

Take also a look at this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15017986/1153884

And this website:
http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/

And you have to make sure that the elements are placed by EmberJS before you call it in jQuery. You can use `didInsertElement:` like this:

```
App.SomeView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application', // I assume from your code it is the application template
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$('a.signup-window').click(function() { // you can use the this.$() ember way of calling
            var signupBox = this.$(this).attr('href').replace("/", ""); 
            /*Here is the rest of the script where I manipulate the template.*/
        });
    }
});
```